# Query on distance to parameter in parameterized complexity

Tags: np-hard, parameterized-complexity

I am a research scholar working in parameterized algorithms. For more information on parameterized complexity please refer to  [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_complexity). Recently, I have come across a problem which is known to be NP-complete on split graphs. Now, it has come to my attention that the problem will not be tractable parameterized by the parameter distance to split, which means that there is no FPT algorithm w.r.t the given parameter. Hence, the problem becomes hard in terms of parameterized complexity. I have got some intuition why it might be true, but couldn't convince myself completely. Can someone elaborate on why this must be true?
TIA

Answer (score 1):

This feels like homework, so I'll just give a hint.

Let $G$ be a split graph.  What is the value of your parameter $d$ then?  What is then the meaning of $f(d) \cdot n^{O(1)}$?

Answer (score 1):

It is a common way to prove that a problem is para-NP-hard for some parameter by proving it is NP-hard on a class with constant value of the parameter. Indeed an $O(f(k)n^c)$ algorithm would imply an $O(f(c’)n^c)$ algorithm for this problem on the given class which is impossible assuming NP not equal P.

An example would be CLIQUE[mimw]. This problem is hard on H-graphs, which has constant mimw. That means it is para-NP-hard parameterized by mimw.

Note that the exsistence of an XP algorithm  for a para-NP-hard problem is also excluded assuming NP is not equal to P.